# How to tune a KDF algorithm to protect a private key?

Tags: bcrypt, pbkdf2, scrypt, kdf

I need to protect a private key RSA-4096 with a key derived by a KDF algorithm.

Instead of hiding any aspect of the algorithm I would like to tune it such that the key derivation is a proof of work big enough to make it impossible to brute-force a decent password of 10 alphanumeric chars

The user runs the key derivation on average hardware.

The attacker has state of the art dedicated hardware and knows **all the details of the key derivation** except for the password. That includes:

- the encrypted RSA key
- the public RSA key
- the password strength specification
- the KDF algorithm source code
- the salt
- the number of iterations used
- any other parameter that might be required

What would be the recommendations for the KDF algorithm (PBKDF2 vs bcrypt vs scrypt) and its parameters?

How would that change if the password also includes both upper/lowercase and special chars?

How would that change if the user runs the key derivation on an average mobile phone?

Comment: A "decent password of 10 alphanumeric characters" is too weak for any KDF you can afford to provide security even close to what RSA-4096 should be able to provide; you're firmly in the "LESS than 64 bits of security" range.  Upgrade to a "cryptographically random password of 25 alphanumeric characters" and you might even be in the 128 bits of security range.

Comment: I was thinking that if the KDF algorithm is tuned well, even if the password doesn't have enough entropy, bruteforce attacs would be really costly. For example if the KDF takes 10s on my machine then the bruteforce would take long enough on any ASIC available on the market